# Woocommerce: Some action hooks not firing inside class

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, customization

I'm busy creating an integration for WooCommerce. I've noticed some hooks work while others don't. Why is this? My code is similar to the following (I've removed everything not related to my question):

```
class WC_Integration_Sage_One_Integration extends WC_Integration {

public static function instance() {    

    return new self(); 

}

public function __construct() {
    // This WORKS
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', array( &$this, 'create_invoice'), 10, 1);

    // This DOES NOT WORK
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_refunded', array(&$this, 'create_credit_note', 10, 2));
}

public function create_invoice($order_id) {
    // Test if hook fires. (It does and mail is sent)
    wp_mail('my@email.com', 'Test', 'Test if hook fires');
}

public function create_credit_note($order_id, $refund_id) {
    // Test if hook fires. (It DOES NOT and no mail is sent)
    wp_mail('my@email.com', 'Test', 'Test if hook fires');
}

}
```

The following actions also don't work:

1. `woocommerce_order_status_changed`
2. `woocommerce_order_status_($status)`

Can someone please tell what I'm doing wrong? This is driving me crazy...

Comment: Why are you using &$this instead of just $this ?

Comment: It's a fallback for PHP4 and as I'm not sure what my user will have I decided to leave it like that. Although I know it's not required.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665086/using-when-passing-function-to-action-hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `array(&$this, 'create_credit_note', 10, 2))`

Should be:  `array(&$this, 'create_credit_note'), 10, 2)`

Comment: Doh... Omg. Sorry for me being completely retarted. I'm going to check it now, but I'm almost positive that was the problem.

Comment: Yup. That's what you get for not taking a break. Thanks alot!